# Pandas Counting Unique Rows

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, counter

I have a pandas data frame similar to:

```
ColA ColB
1    1
1    1
1    1
1    2
1    2
2    1
3    2
```

I want an output that has the same function as [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).  I need to know how many time each row appears (with all of the columns being the same.

In this case the proper output would be:

```
ColA ColB Count
1    1    3
1    2    2
2    1    1
3    2    1
```

I have tried something of the sort:

```
df.groupby(['ColA','ColB']).ColA.count()
```

but this gives me some ugly output I am having trouble formatting

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
print df.groupby(['ColA','ColB']).size().reset_index(name='Count')
   ColA  ColB  Count
0     1     1      3
1     1     2      2
2     2     1      1
3     3     2      1
```

Answer (score 20):

I only needed to **count the unique rows** and have used the [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) alternative as below:

```py
len(df[['ColA', 'ColB']].drop_duplicates())
```

It was twice as fast on my data than `len(df.groupby(['ColA', 'ColB']))`.

Answer (score 3):

Since Pandas 1.1.0 the method [`pandas.DataFrame.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html) is available, which does exactly, what you need. It creates a Series with the unique rows as multi-index and the counts as values:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'ColA': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3], 'ColB': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2]})
pd.options.display.multi_sparse = False  # option to print as requested

print(df.value_counts())                 # requires pandas >= 1.1.0
```

Output, where `ColA` and `ColB` are the multi-index and the third column contains the counts:

```
ColA  ColB
1     1       3
1     2       2
3     2       1
2     1       1
dtype: int64
```